# for loop with comparing to set of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

## Q. what is the right condition for DISPLAYING ONLY equal elements in my array.

heres the code.

```
    int num[]=new int[5];
    int numm[]=new int[5];

    for(int x=0;x<num.length;x++){
        num[x]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num["+(x+1)+"]"));
    }

    for(int x1=0;x1<num.length;x1++){
        num[x1]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num1["+(x1+1)+"]"));
    }

    String tosho="";
        for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
            for(int a1=0;a1<numm.length;a1++){
            if(num[0]==numm[0]){
              num[0]=numm[0];}


            else if(num[1]==numm[1]){
                num[1]=numm[1];}

            else if(num[2]==numm[2]){
                num[2]=numm[2];}

            else if(num[3]==numm[3]){
                num[3]=numm[3];}

            else if(num[4]==numm[4]){
                num[4]=numm[4];}       
        }

    }tosho+=(num[0])+""+(num[1])+""+(num[2])+""+(num[3])+""+(num[4]);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "both "+tosho+" found in array.");
```

when I input 1,2,3,4,5 in first aary

then 1,22,3,4,5 in second array

still it display the 2 or 22, even though they are not equal,,,

Comment: I would use `ArrayList.contains()` to find the intersection, and display that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num[x1]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num1["+(x1+1)+"]"));
```

maybe `numm[x1]`?

You can use this code to fill `tosho`:

```
String tosho="";
for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++) {
    if(num[a]==numm[a]) {
        tosho+=num[a]+",";
    }
}
```

Comment: big mistake for numm[], hahaha

 and thank you for this code.

Answer (score 3):

Why so long code

```
    for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
        for(int a1=0;a1<numm.length;a1++){
        if(num[0]==numm[0]){
          num[0]=numm[0];}


        else if(num[1]==numm[1]){
            num[1]=numm[1];}

        else if(num[2]==numm[2]){
            num[2]=numm[2];}

        else if(num[3]==numm[3]){
            num[3]=numm[3];}

        else if(num[4]==numm[4]){
            num[4]=numm[4];}       
    }
   }
```

do like this

```
    List <Integer> matchedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
        for(int a1=0;a1<numm.length;a1++){
            if(num[a]==numm[a1]){
                matchedElements.add(num[a]);
           }
        }
    }
    Integer[] mached = matchedElements.toArray(new Integer[matchedElements.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mached));
```

Comment: Yes it can be shortened but is the the logic not still wrong? for the problem described.

Answer (score 2):

you start your if squence with

```
if(num[0]==numm[0]){
          num[0]=numm[0];}
```

and then you are using ELSE which means that it will be evaluated ONLY if the first if is not executing. It means that after you change the first element of the array, no other will be changed as there will be no ELSE since num[0] will equal numm[0]. Remove all "else" words and it should work.

Comment: but still it does not display the ONLY equal elements.

Comment: that's because you don't even need those two loops if you check every element of the array manually (all those ifs)

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is wrong. you never assign values to `numm` variable.

The nested loops are no effect in the code. there no usage of `a` and `a1` loop variable.

I added an additional array to store same values called `sameValues` and assign same values.

```
int num[]=new int[5]; int numm[]=new int[5]; int sameValues[] = new int[5];

for(int x=0;x<num.length;x++){
        num[x]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num["+(x+1)+"]"));
        }

for(int x1=0;x1<num.length;x1++){
        numm[x1]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num1["+(x1+1)+"]"));
        }

int counter = 0;
String tosho="";
for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
        for(int a1=0;a1<numm.length;a1++){
                if(num[a] == numm[a1]){
                        sameValues[counter] = num[a];
                        counter++;
                 }
        }
}

for(int x=0;x<counter ;x++){
        tosho+=(num[x]) + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These two nested loops

```
for(int a=0;a<num.length;a++){
    for(int a1=0;a1<numm.length;a1++){
    ...
```

are useless.

You're not using in any way the variables `a` and `a1`.

Instead, you could simply iterate form 0 to array length and check the elements with same index for equality.